# Deploying a datasource w/ JAAS login module as a .sar in jboss

Tags: jboss, datasource, sar

Does anyone have experience bundling a datasource (-ds.xml) definition + login-config.xml as a service archive in jboss?  I've been fighting with this for awhile to no avail.  I'm just looking for some pointers on how I should be laying the .sar out.  I want the .sar to ultimately live in a .ear.  Any pointers greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is relatively straightforward task.

Your EAR file needs to have following layout:

```
my-app.ear
    |+ META-INF
       |+ applications.xml and jboss-app.xml
    |+ myapp.war
    |+ myapp.jar
    |+ lib
    |+ my-ds.xml
    |+ my-login-module-service.xml
```

where my-ds.xml contains datasource definition as usual. my-login-module-service.xml defines MBean based on the DynamicLoginConfig class. These modules are then referenced within jboss-app.xml (custom JBoss deployment descriptor) as demostrated here:

```
<jboss-app>
<module>
    <service>my-login-module-service.xml</service>
</module>

<module>
    <service>my-ds.xml</service>
</module>
</jboss-app>
```

Easiest way how to create Login Module definition is to use support for embedded XML documents as attributes values. Such a config (my-login-module-service.xml) will looks like this:

```
<server>
    <mbean code="org.jboss.security.auth.login.DynamicLoginConfig"
        name="jboss:service=DynamicLoginConfig">
        <attribute name="PolicyConfig" serialDataType="jbxb">
        <jaas:policy xsi:schemaLocation="urn:jboss:security-config:4.1 resource:security-config_4_1.xsd" xmlns:jaas="urn:jboss:security-config:4.1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <jaas:application-policy name="userinrole">
            <jaas:authentication>
                <jaas:login-module code="org.jboss.security.auth.spi.XMLLoginModule" flag="required">
                <jaas:module-option name="my-policy-123">
                <ur:users xsi:schemaLocation="urn:jboss:user-roles:1.0 resource:user-roles_1_0.xsd" xmlns:ur="urn:jboss:user-roles:1.0">
                    <ur:user name="admin" password="admin123">
                        <ur:role name="MyUserRole"></ur:role>
                        <ur:role name="AdminUser"></ur:role
                    </ur:user>
                </ur:users>
                </jaas:module-option>
                <jaas:module-option name="unauthenticatedIdentity">guest</jaas:module-option>
                </jaas:login-module>
        </jaas:authentication>
        </jaas:application-policy>
        </jaas:policy>
    </attribute>
        <depends optional-attribute-name="LoginConfigService">jboss.security:service=XMLLoginConfig</depends>
        <depends optional-attribute-name="SecurityManagerService">jboss.security:service=JaasSecurityManager</depends>
    </mbean>
</server>
```

You can verify successful deployment using JNDIVIew bean (java:/jaas/my-policy-123 in this example).

For deployment including custom classes it's better to choose SAR archive deployment together with custom code. In such a case you can separate MBean definition and Login Module config (META-INF/jboss-service.xml) :

```
<server>
<mbean code="org.jboss.security.auth.login.DynamicLoginConfig" name="jboss:service=DynamicLoginConfig">
    <attribute name="AuthConfig">META-INF/login-config.xml</attribute>
    <depends optional-attribute-name="LoginConfigService">jboss.security:service=XMLLoginConfig</depends>
    <depends optional-attribute-name="SecurityManagerService">jboss.security:service=JaasSecurityManager</depends>
</mbean>
</server>
```

META-INF/login-config.xml will then contain your policy configuration.

I'm using this approach on JBoss AS 4.x.